# Passing a prop to a vuejs mixin but property is undefined

Tags: vue.js, mixins, vue-mixin

When I try to pass a prop to a mixin I get a `Cannot read property of undefined error`.

Am I doing something wrong or how else can I overcome this?

`mixins/BarMixin.js`:

```
export default baz => {
  return {
    // my mixin code...
  }
}
```

`components/FooComponent.vue`:

```
<script>
import BarMixin from '@/mixins/BarMixin.js'

export default {
  mixins: [BarMixin(this.baz)],
  props: {
    bar: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

and then I try to use it, in something like this:

`pages/foo.vue`

```
<template>
  <FooComponent :baz="true" />
</template>

<script>
import FooComponent from '@/components/FooComponent.vue'
export default {
  components: {
    FooComponent,
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, are the props `bar` and `baz` supposed to be the same thing?

Answer (score 3):

You can workaround by accessing these properties from the component as if the mixing is the component.
To make the property 'dynamic', you can pass the name of the field you need to access inside the mixin.
Like this:

```
function myMixin(propName) {
  return {
    computed: {
      mixinComputed () {
        return this[propName] + 'somethingElse';
      }
    }
  };
}
```

If you want to pass an inner property of an object, like 'user.name' to the mixin, you can create a computed on the outer component or, make it inside the mixin itself:

```
function myMixin(propName1, propName2) {
  return {
    computed: {
      mixinComputed () {
        return this.parsedPropValue1 + this.parsedPropValue2;
      },
      parsedPropValue1 () {
        return this.parsePath(propName1);
      },
      parsedPropValue2 () {
        return this.parsePath(propName2);
      }
    },
    methods: {
      parsePath(path) {
        if (!path)
         return;
        const split = path.split('.');
        return split.reduce((acc, curr) => acc && acc[curr], this);
      }
    }
  };
}
```

Usage:

```
mixins: [myMixin('user.address.street', 'obj')]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to dynamically pass parameters to Vue mixins.

However you can use this functional approach as an alternative:

```
 function BarMixin(param) {
  return {
    data() {
      return {
       ....
      }
    }
    // your mixin code
  }
 }
```

Comment: I don't understand how that solves the problem. As a matter of fact I am already returning the mixin like that. Is there a way to dynamically add the mixin maybe then?